# Stored Water Volume at Variant Temperatures and supply at set temperature how does this increase volume

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, water, volume

Could some one help me with a formula to solve this question

If I have stored volume of 750L at 60Deg C water in an insulated storage vessel and I increase this set temperature to 75 Deg c, How much more will I increase my stored volume of 60 Deg C.

I would appreciate a simple laymen's formula as this is a calculation i regularly have to make at varied temperatures

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

$$\Delta V=\beta V \Delta T$$

Coefficient of volume expansion *β(1/ºC)*

For water (above 4Cº) it is 0.000210 [source](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/13-2-thermal-expansion-of-solids-and-liquids)

For ΔΤ=+15C and V=750L you get ΔV=+2.3625 L (~0.3% increase in volume)

If it was a temperature drop ΔΤ=-15C you get ΔV=-2.3625 L (~0.3% decrease in volume)

Answer (score 1):

One thing to watch out for: if it's a sealed container the expanded volume needs a place to go. Water has VERY low compressibility. If there is any air in the container, the air will be compressed first and the final pressure will depend on the amount of air in the container. If the amount of water expansion equals the amount of air, the pressure will basically increase by 1 atmosphere (100 kPa).

If it's a sealed container without (or only very little) air, the pressure will increase by 10s of millions of Pascal. This can be VERY dangerous.

Comment: Many thanks , this is hot water stored in a vessel  for supply at points of showers. The necessary safety valves, pressure release, expansion valves  are standard with all installations.  I am just trying to figure out if we increase the temperature of water stored in this vessel which is 750L to 75Deg c instead of 60deg c how much more water can be supplied if tempered down from 75 deg to 60 deg at the point of outlet

Answer (score 0):

According to the table in [this](http://www.csgnetwork.com/waterinformation.html) website the volume $V$ would increase by about 1% for a 15C rise at 60C, (volume is inversely proportional to density, so do $\frac{1}{V}$).

Perhaps you could use the table to make a graph to help you quickly find the volume change for different temperatures.

Comment: Thank you, that was a suprise i really though that it would increase the volume of supply at 60Deg way beyhond 1%. I need to get my head around this.

Comment: @ Bronwynn  yes, but also see the safety message of Hilmar's answer